# JQuery add text inside <script>

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I am receiving a string via query string and I wish to add this string after a given part of text inside `<script>`.

The part of the HTML code where the `<script>` appears is:

```
<span id="e641370446" class="inline"></span><script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/eval("var a=\"697OHPkfxK+cMU-8tFgWnE4zQ3GYSIvNDpi_0Co5eVlw@yZTJmu1B.hrXqRdAsj2Lba\";var b=a.split(\"\").sort().join(\"\");var c=\"wsRdrdUVAmXmwr7wr.7lR\";var d=\"\";for(var e=0;e<c.length;e++)d+=b.charAt(a.indexOf(c.charAt(e)));document.getElementById(\"e641370446\").innerHTML=\"<a class=\\\"inline mail\\\" href=\\\"mailto:\"+d+\"?subject=[Curso] SEO Atípico%20Contato&body=Nome:%20%0D%0ATelefone:%20%0D%0AMensagem:%20%0D%0A\\\">envie um e-mail para cursos@atipico.com.br</a>\"")/*]]>*/</script>
```

Note that this script is encripted and also is always preceeded by a span, witch has each time a different id.

The part I wish to modify is `"mailto:\"+d+\"?subject=[Curso]"` inserting the query string value right after `[Curso]`, like this:

```
[Curso] string
```

I am using "jQuery-URL-Parser" plugin to parse the url.

Besides, this script is a mailto link, so, I can make the operation only in the event of the click...

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying you want to insert something into that big ugly eval with jquery?

Comment: Eval itself is close.  Problem is the eval has already been evaluated.  The eval did however create elements on the page which you can now work with.  But why does that eval even exist?

Comment: You can see a living example here: http://atipico.com.br

Comment: PHP encrypts your E-mail address and generates the javascript that decrypts it. More about it here:http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=27550

Comment: There is a reason that EVAL is similar to EVIL ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the span ID, this is easy to solve. Use jQuery to change the DOM, not the contents of the script.

```
var spanId = 'e641370446', // get this from wherever
    $link = $('#' + spanId).children('a.inline.mail');
    
$link.prop('href', $link.prop('href') + '&key=value');
```

See for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/E8HC5/

---

***Edit:***

> I am trying to adapt your code but it is not working. In the case I have to add the string after the word "[Curso]"... any idea?

You can use something as simple as [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```
...
$link.prop('href', $link.prop('href').replace('[Curso]', '[Curso] some text'));
...
```

Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/f2sKa/

---

#### Solution (added by [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559742/roger)):

Based on your help, this is what another folk suggested:

```
$('a.mail').click(function (event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var linkUrl = $this.attr('href');

    linkUrl = linkUrl.replace('[Curso]', '[Curso] some text');
    $this.attr('href', linkUrl);
});
```

Comment: Can I choose to make this somehow with a click event? That's because the id is always changing, so I do not know it.

Comment: I am trying to adapt your code but it is not working. In the case I have to add the string after the word "[Curso]"... any idea?

Comment: This made me get the link clik: $('span.inline').click(function(){ alert('Hi'); }); But now I have to filter the link content somehow...

Comment: See my edit. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `click` event, though.

Comment: The click event would help me to modify the clicked link,  once I do not know the ID because it is randomic. I think we are just steps from the solution.

Comment: Sorry, [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) was added in jQuery 1.6 (which was only released on May 2nd, so it's still very new). You must be using an older version of jQuery (which is fine!), so just use `.attr()` instead of `.prop()` and it'll fix that problem.